# Chi-square in ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, chi-squared-test

I am comparing models that I created with the lmer function from the lme4 package using ANOVA. Paricipants and verbs are my random factors, and RT are the Reaction Times that I measured. From the little statistics that I know, I would expect F-statictic values in the output, but instead I get chi-square.

Could you please help me understand why I get that, or whether I should (or could) change that?
Here is my code and output:

```
m0<-lmer((sqrt(RT))~(1|Participant)+(1|Verbs), data=data, REML=FALSE)
m1<-lmer((sqrt(RT))~(1|Participant)+(1|Verbs)+verbT, data=data, REML=FALSE)

anova(m0,m1)


Data: data
Models:
m0: (sqrt(RT)) ~ (1 | Participant) + (1 | Verbs)
m1: (sqrt(RT)) ~ (1 | Participant) + (1 | Verbs) + verbT
   Df     AIC     BIC logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
m0  4 -693.68 -672.44 350.84  -701.68                         
m1  5 -693.71 -667.16 351.85  -703.71 2.0238      1     0.1548
```